# How can I test if a instance of a class is a specific generic type?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection

Say I have a simple generic class as follows

```
public class MyGenericClass<t>
{
   public T {get;set;}
}
```

How can I test if an instance of a class is this a `MyGenericClass`? For example I want to do something like this:

```
MyGenericClass x = new MyGenericClass<string>();
bool a = x is MyGenericClass;
bool b = x.GetType() == typeof(MyGenericClass);
```

Yet I can't just reference `MyGenericClass`. Visual studio always wants me to write `MyGenericClass<something>`.

Answer (score 2):

To test if your instance is a type of `MyGenericClass<T>`, you can write something like this.

```
MyGenericClass<string> myClass = new MyGenericClass<string>();
bool b = myClass.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(MyGenericClass<>);
```

If you want to be able to declare your object as `MyGenericClass` instead of `MyGenericClass<string>`, it would need a non-generic base of `MyGenericClass` to be part of the inheritance tree. But at that point, you would only be able to refer to properties/methods on the base unless you later cast to the derived generic type. You cannot omit the type parameter when directly declaring a generic instance.*

*You can, of course, opt to use type inference and write

```
var myClass = new MyGenericClass<string>();
```

**Edit:** Adam Robinson makes a good point in the comments, say you have `class Foo : MyGenericClass<string>`. The testing code above would not identify an instance of Foo as a `MyGenericClass<>`, but you can still write code to test it.

```
Func<object, bool> isMyGenericClassInstance = obj =>
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return false; // otherwise will get NullReferenceException

        Type t = obj.GetType().BaseType;
        if (t != null)
        {
            if (t.IsGenericType)
                return t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(MyGenericClass<>);
        }

        return false;
    };

bool willBeTrue = isMyGenericClassInstance(new Foo());
bool willBeFalse = isMyGenericClassInstance("foo");
```

Comment: Note this is won't work if the class is *derived* from a generic form of the class. In other words, `public class Foo : MyGenericClass<string> { }` wouldn't qualify.

Comment: @Adam, good point. You can write code to go a bit further to test. I'll add *an idea* on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<int> testInt = new List<int>();
List<string> testString = new List<string>();

if (testInt .GetType().Equals(testString.GetType()))
 Console.WriteLine("Y");
else Console.WriteLine("N");
```

its 'N'

and

```
testInt.GetType().Equals(typeof(List<int>))
is true
```

but if u want just class name

```
testInt.GetType().FullName
```

Answer (score 0):

You could, if desired, make the generic class implement some arbitrary (possibly empty) interface.  Testing whether some object was of the general generic class would then simply be a matter of testing whether it implemented that interface.  No need to explicitly use reflection.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following (as I found out all the suggestions didn't work for me.

```
  public static bool IsGenericTypeOf(Type vtype, Type target) {
     return
           vtype.IsGenericType
        && target.ContainsGenericParameters
        && vtype.Name == target.Name
        && vtype.Assembly == target.Assembly
        && vtype.Module == target.Module
        ;
  }
```